# apply css to empty value

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
.ReadOnlySettingsListField {
    width:150px;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

My html is as follows:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <div id="value1" class="ReadOnlySettingsListField ">{{ value1 }}</div>
             <div id="value2" class="ReadOnlySettingsListField ">&nbsp;</div>
             <div id="value3" class="ReadOnlySettingsListField ">{{ value3 }}</div>          
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

My problem is whenever the values: value1 or value3 are empty,the div does not look the way it should i.e. The background color only shows as a wee thin strip at the top.
If the value1 or value3 have any text at all then it looks as expected (150 wide, background color=eeeeee)

How can I make the css to apply to 'empty' values as well?

Comment: The CSS *does* apply to empty elements as well, but you haven't specified any height values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `min-width` and `min-height` property in your css class like this

```
.ReadOnlySettingsListField 
{
 width:150px; 
 float: left; 
 padding: 2px; 
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 min-width:150px;
 min-height:100px;

}
```